# Bootswatch - dropdown menu is not working

Tags: html, css, bootswatch

I'm trying to integrate a custom theme for bootstrap

the theme i want to use is [bootswatch](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/)

the only problem i'm currently facing is that the dropdown menu in the navigation bar is not working.

this is my code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+ENW/yibaokMnme+vBLnHMphUYxHs34h9lpdbSLuAwGkOKFRl4C34WkjazBtb7eT" crossorigin="anonymous">
     
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
    
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">Bootswatch</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="themes">Themes <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes">
                    <li><a href="../default/">Default</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="../cerulean/">Cerulean</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../cosmo/">Cosmo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../cyborg/">Cyborg</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../darkly/">Darkly</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../flatly/">Flatly</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../journal/">Journal</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../lumen/">Lumen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../paper/">Paper</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../readable/">Readable</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../sandstone/">Sandstone</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../simplex/">Simplex</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../slate/">Slate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../spacelab/">Spacelab</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../superhero/">Superhero</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../united/">United</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../yeti/">Yeti</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="../help/">Help</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="http://news.bootswatch.com">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="download">Flatly <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="download">
                    <li><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/bootswatch/jmg3gykg/">Open Sandbox</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="./bootstrap.min.css">bootstrap.min.css</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./bootstrap.css">bootstrap.css</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="./variables.less">variables.less</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./bootswatch.less">bootswatch.less</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="./_variables.scss">_variables.scss</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./_bootswatch.scss">_bootswatch.scss</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
    
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="http://builtwithbootstrap.com/" target="_blank">Built With Bootstrap</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://wrapbootstrap.com/?ref=bsw" target="_blank">WrapBootstrap</a></li>
              </ul>
    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="../" class="navbar-brand">Bootswatch</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="themes">Themes <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes">
                <li><a href="../default/">Default</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="../cerulean/">Cerulean</a></li>
                <li><a href="../cosmo/">Cosmo</a></li>
                <li><a href="../cyborg/">Cyborg</a></li>
                <li><a href="../darkly/">Darkly</a></li>
                <li><a href="../flatly/">Flatly</a></li>
                <li><a href="../journal/">Journal</a></li>
                <li><a href="../lumen/">Lumen</a></li>
                <li><a href="../paper/">Paper</a></li>
                <li><a href="../readable/">Readable</a></li>
                <li><a href="../sandstone/">Sandstone</a></li>
                <li><a href="../simplex/">Simplex</a></li>
                <li><a href="../slate/">Slate</a></li>
                <li><a href="../spacelab/">Spacelab</a></li>
                <li><a href="../superhero/">Superhero</a></li>
                <li><a href="../united/">United</a></li>
                <li><a href="../yeti/">Yeti</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="../help/">Help</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="http://news.bootswatch.com">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="download">Flatly <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="download">
                <li><a href="http://jsfiddle.net/bootswatch/jmg3gykg/">Open Sandbox</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="./bootstrap.min.css">bootstrap.min.css</a></li>
                <li><a href="./bootstrap.css">bootstrap.css</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="./variables.less">variables.less</a></li>
                <li><a href="./bootswatch.less">bootswatch.less</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="./_variables.scss">_variables.scss</a></li>
                <li><a href="./_bootswatch.scss">_bootswatch.scss</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="http://builtwithbootstrap.com/" target="_blank">Built With Bootstrap</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://wrapbootstrap.com/?ref=bsw" target="_blank">WrapBootstrap</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to make a diff between the two bigs scripts to see what's different ?

Comment: DIFF: ordering of js/css tags and jQuery version 2.1.1->3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I use bootstrap 4.3.1 instead of 3.3.7 to fix this problem. 
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js 
Maybe you can try it.